# AppEngine, how to use static html files

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Please, help me, how I can use html files in my appengine application for Java environment (Java SDK)?
When I open it in my browser I got error: HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /myapp/. Reason: NOT_FOUND

Comment: Do you have a entry for the static files in your app.yaml?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on what you intend to do :

If you want to serve a static page inside your app :
 import (or create) the html page in the folder : YourProject/war
Then you can call it with a relative link in your application:

`<a href = 'MyPage.html'> My link </a>`

---

If you want to start the app with a static page, then you must declare it in : YourPRoject/war/WEB-INF/web.xml file, by adding somthing like this this :

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>sign.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

---

I hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look through the [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/staticfiles.html) documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to the `app.yaml` file and it worked for me. This declaration needs to be made right after app_version. Please note that I have placed my html files in the main directory itself.

```
handlers:
-   url: /(.*\.html)
    static_files: \1
    upload: (.*html)
```

Comment: Unable to find property 'static_files' on class: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppYaml$Handler